# What is the Meaning of the equation $\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}=\left|f(\theta,\phi)\right|^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In the "Preface for Students" of the book "Quantum Field Theory" by Mark Srednicki is a set of equations.  Quoting from the author: "In order to be prepared to undertake the study of quantum field theory, you should recognize and understand the following equations".  Then follows a list of equations.  I understand the source and meaning and application of each of them except for one.  The one equation is:
$$
\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}=\left|\,f(\theta,\phi)\,\right|^2
$$
I could hazard guesses thinking that it might have something to do with spin state probability with respect to solid angle but that is merely based on the symbols used, not from any understanding of the equation.

Comment: Noted that my guess was a bit off.  I was thinking of $\sigma$ in terms of spin operator.  I think I forgot $\sigma$ was also used for cross section and it definitely makes more sense with that definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12528/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This equation is the expression for differential scattering cross-section $\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}$ (cross-section per solid angle $d\Omega = d\phi d\theta \sin(\theta)$) in terms of the scattering amplitude $f(\theta,\phi)$.

The meaning of the scattering amplitude is that the asymptotic form (far from the origin of the scattering at $r=0$) of the *difference* of the full wave-function from the "incident wave" is given by
$$
\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}f(\theta,\phi)\;.
$$

See, e.g., "Quantum Mechanics" by Albert Messiah, chapter 10.

Comment: I just edited my title to ask the question.  Thanks for the answer.  I should be embarrassed, my undergrad Physics education actually used Messiah's book (just volume 1) but then that was almost 50 years ago!  I will look that up, I still have Messiah's two volume set and I am now thinking that I probably didn't even look in that text.

Comment: Scattering is near the end of volume one... chapter 10... see also volume 2, chapter 19.

Comment: I found it.  I will have to give a brief run through of the material but not tonight.